# Python & Active Directory : Signin as a computer ( ms-active-directory )

Tags: python, windows, active-directory

i have a question concerning the etablishing of a connection to the AD via python. The standard configuration looks like this :

```
from ldap3 import NTLM
from ms_active_directory import ADDomain

domain_dns_name = 'example.local'

domain = ADDomain( domain_dns_name ,
                   source_ip = '10.0.2.15' ,
                   netbios_name = 'EXAMPLE' ,
                   discover_ldap_servers = False ,
                   ldap_servers_or_uris = [ '10.0.2.15' ] ,
                   encrypt_connections = False ,
                   discover_kerberos_servers = False ,
                   kerberos_uris = [ ] ,
                   auto_configure_kerberos_client = False )
```

If i try to etablish a connection using user authentification, it works fine :

```
session = domain.create_session_as_user('Administrator@example.local', 'test1234!' )
ntlm_session =  domain.create_session_as_user('EXAMPLE\Administrator', 'test1234!', authentication_mechanism=NTLM)
```

In the documentation of `ms-active-directory`is written, that it's also possible to use the computer name. So i created a computer manually in Active Directory ( test environment ) and tried to execute following code :

```
domain.create_session_as_computer( computer_name = 'Tester' , 
                            computer_password = 'test1234!' ,
                            check_name_format = True , 
                            authentication_mechanism = 'NTLM' )
```

But it always fails with following DomainConnect error message :

```
DomainConnectException('Failed to bind connection to {} - please check the credentials and '
ms_active_directory.exceptions.DomainConnectException: Failed to bind connection to ldap://10.0.2.15:5000 - please check the credentials and authentication mechanism in use. LDAP result: {'result': 49, 'description': 'invalidCredentials', 'dn': '', 'message': '8009030C: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903D3, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 2030, v3839\x00', 'referrals': None, 'saslCreds': None, 'type': 'bindResponse'}
```

Of course, because i don't know the password of the  computer 'Tester', so i have no clue how to use `create_session_as_computer` , it seems impossible to get the machines password, which will be changed every 30 day. It would be also ok to change the machine password for test purposes.

How do i realize to logon on the server with the computer name ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Best regards
NumeroUnoDE

Comment: Nobody, who can support me with this issue ?

Comment: Are you sure the computer account name is `Tester` and not `Tester$`?